# JS or CSS is not working when copied from codepen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was looking for good image animations online and found this however when i download copy all the html css and js as well as the hidden css and js in the pens settings it doesn't work at all in a local file.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMGYwN

i have tried downloading the js and css and puting it all into the html file with no avail

index.html:

```
</html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/splitting@1.0.5/dist/splitting-cells.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="tiler">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1067" />
</div>

<div class="tiler">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1061" />
</div>

<div class="tiler">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1057" />
</div>


<div class="tiler">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1052" />
</div>


<div class="tiler">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1043" />
</div>


<div class="tiler">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1055" />
</div>


<div class="tiler">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1036" />
</div>


<div class="tiler">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1037" />
</div>


<div class="tiler">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1039" />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/splitting@1.0.5/dist/splitting.js"></script>
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
console.clear();

Splitting({
  target: '.tiler',
  by: 'cells',
  rows: 3,
  columns: 3,
  image: true
}); //Image('.tiler-overlay', { rows: 3, cols: 3 });
```

style.css:

```
.tiler {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 33.3%;
  margin: auto;
}

.tiler img { 
  display: block;  
  margin: auto; 
  max-width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

.tiler .cell-grid {
  background-position: center center;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  z-index: 10;

  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 600px;

  perspective: 30px;

  // &:before {
  //   content: '';
  //   display: block;
  //   visibility: visible;
  //   position: absolute;
  //   top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  //   margin: auto;
  //   box-shadow: 0 1em 2em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  // }
}

.tiler .cell { 
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;

  transform: translateZ(-15px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.4s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.65,.01,.15,1.33);//, linear;

  /* The center character index */
  --center-x: calc((var(--col-total) - 1) / 2);
  --center-y: calc((var(--row-total) - 1) / 2);

  /* Offset from center, positive & negative */
  --offset-x: calc(var(--col-index) - var(--center-x));
  --offset-y: calc(var(--row-index) - var(--center-y));

  /* Absolute distance from center, only positive */
  --distance-x: calc(
    (var(--offset-x) * var(--offset-x)) / var(--center-x)
  );

  /* Absolute distance from center, only positive */
  --distance-y: calc(
    (var(--offset-y) * var(--offset-y)) / var(--center-y)
  );

  transition-delay: calc( 0.1s * var(--distance-y) + 0.1s * var(--distance-x) );
}

// .tiler { transition: z-index 0.3s linear; }

.tiler-overlay { z-index: 2; }
.tiler:hover {

  .cell { 
    // pointer-events: auto;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1; 

  }
}


html { height: 100%; display: flex; background: #323643; }
body { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; max-width: 800px; padding: 2em; margin: auto; }
```

Comment: you can try CTRL+F5

Comment: Are the folders in the correct place relative to the url (not file) that is serving them (as you have used relative paths)

Comment: You are using SCSS syntax in a .css file. That isn't going to work.

Comment: Please check the below snippet. Everything was working fine

Comment: This is probably not the cause of the problem, but you also have a typo, the first tag should be `<html>` not `</html>`

Comment: I cannot see you importing the Splitting.js file anywhere, did you check the JS console? That call to `Splitting({...})` is probably resulting in a `undefined` error.

Comment: @RaulSauco It's at the bottom of the HTML.

Comment: @Turnip you are right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working snippet for the same. You need to convert Saas to css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/splitting@1.0.5/dist/splitting-cells.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/splitting@1.0.5/dist/splitting.js"></script>
  <style>
 /*convert saas to css*/
    .tiler {
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 33.3%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    .tiler img {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    
    .tiler .cell-grid {
      background-position: center center;
      margin: auto;
      position: fixed;
      top: 1em;
      bottom: 1em;
      left: 1em;
      right: 1em;
      z-index: 10;
      max-width: 1000px;
      max-height: 600px;
      -webkit-perspective: 30px;
      perspective: 30px;
    }
    
    .tiler .cell {
      pointer-events: none;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-15px);
      transform: translateZ(-15px);
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: transform, opacity;
      transition-property: transform, opacity, -webkit-transform;
      transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.4s;
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.01, 0.15, 1.33);
      /* The center character index */
      --center-x: calc((var(--col-total) - 1) / 2);
      --center-y: calc((var(--row-total) - 1) / 2);
      /* Offset from center, positive & negative */
      --offset-x: calc(var(--col-index) - var(--center-x));
      --offset-y: calc(var(--row-index) - var(--center-y));
      /* Absolute distance from center, only positive */
      --distance-x: calc((var(--offset-x) * var(--offset-x)) / var(--center-x));
      /* Absolute distance from center, only positive */
      --distance-y: calc((var(--offset-y) * var(--offset-y)) / var(--center-y));
      transition-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--distance-y) + 0.1s * var(--distance-x));
    }
    
    .tiler-overlay {
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .tiler:hover .cell {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    html {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      background: #323643;
    }
    
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      max-width: 800px;
      padding: 2em;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tiler">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1067" />
  </div>

  <div class="tiler">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1061" />
  </div>

  <div class="tiler">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1057" />
  </div>


  <div class="tiler">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1052" />
  </div>


  <div class="tiler">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1043" />
  </div>


  <div class="tiler">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1055" />
  </div>


  <div class="tiler">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1036" />
  </div>


  <div class="tiler">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1037" />
  </div>


  <div class="tiler">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1039" />
  </div>
  <script>
    console.clear();

    Splitting({
      target: '.tiler',
      by: 'cells',
      rows: 3,
      columns: 3,
      image: true
    }); //Image('.tiler-overlay', { rows: 3, cols: 3 });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope that you are importing stylesheet using correct path

Comment: Glad that I could help you. You didn't convert saas into css in your code. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..............

```
//<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
//<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Add

```
<!doctype html>
```

at the first line of html file.
Write the style.css under splitting-cells.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/splitting@1.0.5/dist/splitting-cells.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

no need to use ./ if the css folder in the same directory
also can remove ./ if the js folder in the same diretory